# Refused to load the script because it violates the following CSP using Manifest V3

Tags: javascript, google-api, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to build a *chrome extension* that will transcribe voice as text into a Google Document. I am getting 4 errors similar to this one *Refused to load the script 'https://apis.google.com/js/api.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.* From what I've read this problem was fixed in Manifest V2 by adding the respective links into the *CSP* key
`"content_security_policy": { "extension_pages": "script-src 'self' url1 url2 etc... ; script-src-elem ''object-src 'self'" }`
But in manifest V3 I can only add 1 keyword or the chrome extension will not let me upload the files.

I've also tried adding them to the *sandbox* key in CSP and in *host_permissions* but same result.

Comment: This API can't be used as a script in an extension page. You can use `fetch` directly to the remote API, not via the gapi object, but that would require you to make the requests explicitly/manually. The only way to use gapi object in ManifestV3 is to do it inside a [sandboxed frame](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox) inside your popup or chrome.offscreen document

Comment: @wOxxOm can you provide me an example of how to do it with a sandboxed frame? I've added the sandbox key and linked my HTML file but I get the same errors.